# Restarting Upstart instance processes

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I am running multiple instances of a worker as described in this answer: [Starting multiple upstart instances automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681974/starting-multiple-upstart-instances-automatically)

**Question: Can I restart all instances at once?**

To start my workers I can do:

> initctl start my-workers

Which then allows me to do:

> initctl status worker N=1 worker (1) start/running, process 551
>
> initctl status worker N=2 worker (2) start/running, process 552

Is there a way to do something like this:

> initctl restart my-workers

I would like to be able to restart all instances without having to know how many are running.

Here is my my-workers.conf

```
start on stopped cloud-init
stop on shutdown

env NUM_WORKERS=4

script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
    do
      start worker N=$i
    done
end script
```

And worker.conf

```
stop on shutdown

chdir /path/to/current

respawn

instance $N

script
  exec su -c "/home/worker/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c 'bundle exec rake work 2>&1 >> /var/log/worker-$N.log'" worker
end script
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In `worker.conf` you just need to change this line:

```
stop on shutdown
```

To:

```
stop on stopping my-workers
```

And change `my-workers.conf` to use `pre-start` instead of `script`:

```
pre-start script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
  do
    start worker N=$i
  done
end script
```

Now `my-workers` will keep state: since the work happens in `pre-start`, the `my-workers` main process won't exist and so won't exit.  `stop on stopping my-workers` causes the workers to stop whenever `my-workers` is stopped. Then of course when it starts up again it will start the workers again.

(FYI, `stop on shutdown` does nothing, as `shutdown` is not a system event. `man upstart-events` for all the defined events) so you should also change my-workers to `stop on runlevel [06]`

Comment: took me a while to understand what you mean, but once I got it ... *mind blown*

Comment: @Evgeny same here, haha. If like me, and probably Evgeny, you just spent 5 minutes trying to understand what is going here: basically my-workers.conf spawns multiple upstart scripts and exits, but each worker.conf now has the line `stop on stopping my-workers`, so when you attempt to stop the already stopped my-workers process, the workers will still listen to it and die. So "restarting" my-workers, even though it wasn't really running before, has the effect of killing the workers (stop) and running the pre-start script (start) again, spawning them again.

Comment: It works but it is quite hackish. `service my-workers start` will hang, in fact. The Upstart documentation states `All job files must have either an exec or script stanza.` `pre-start script and post-stop script - These are not expected to start the process, in fact, they can't.`. Maybe it is better just to create another job for stopping or restarting workers.

Comment: This is (now?) defined as an abstract job: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#abstract-job - so it seems to be alright.

Answer (score 7):

I tried it with the example from above and SpamapS answer, I received:

```
init: my-workers pre-start process (22955) terminated with status 127
```

In `/var/log/upstart/my-workers.log` I found the problem:

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 6: /proc/self/fd/9: end: not found
```

The `end` of the for-loop in `my-workers.conf` seemed to be wrong syntax.
I replaced

```
script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
    do
      start worker N=$i
    done
  end
end script
```

with

```
script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
  do
    start worker N=$i
  done
end script
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding to the worker.conf one more event:

```
stop on shutdown or workers-stop
```

Then you can call from the command line

```
sudo initctl emit workers-stop
```

You can add similar event to start workers. To achieve restarting all workers create a task that will emit workers-stop and then workers-start events.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to have a process that executes many `stop` and `start` commands for all your `N=1`, `N=2` combination.

A simple way to do this is a couple of bash `for` loops inside an `exec script` stanza. However, if the processes take some time to stop (e.g. because they are working on something and they are accepting `SIGTERM` after having processed their current job) this is inefficient as you have to wait for one to stop before sending the signal to the next one.

Therefore, I built an Upstart script that stops them in parallel at https://github.com/elifesciences/builder-base-formula/blob/master/elife/config/etc-init-multiple-processes-parallel.conf

The script is compiled by Salt using as input a map of process names to how many are there. Here is a sample result:

```
description "(Re)starts all instances, in parallel"
# http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
task
script
    timeout=300
    echo "--------"

    echo "Current status of 5 elife-bot-worker processes"
    echo "Now is" $(date -Iseconds)
    for i in `seq 1 5`
    do
        status elife-bot-worker ID=$i || true
    done
    echo "Stopping asynchronously 5 elife-bot-worker processes"
    echo "Now is" $(date -Iseconds)
    for i in `seq 1 5`
    do
        (stop elife-bot-worker ID=$i &) || true
    done

    for i in `seq 1 5`
    do
        echo "Waiting for elife-bot-worker $i to stop"
        echo "Now is" $(date -Iseconds)
        counter=0
        while true
        do
            if [ "$counter" -gt "$timeout" ]
            then
                echo "It shouldn't take more than $timeout seconds to kill all the elife-bot-worker processes"
                exit 1
            fi
            status elife-bot-worker ID=$i 2>&1 | grep "Unknown instance" && break
            sleep 1
            counter=$((counter + 1))
        done
    done
    echo "Stopped all elife-bot-worker processes"

    echo "Starting 5 elife-bot-worker processes"
    for i in `seq 1 5`
    do
        start elife-bot-worker ID=$i
    done
    echo "Started 5 elife-bot-worker processes"

end script
```