# Upstart task hangs after it finishes successfully

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I've got an Upstart task that starts multiple instances of a service based on [Starting multiple upstart instances automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681974/starting-multiple-upstart-instances-automatically) and [Restarting Upstart instance processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084025/restarting-upstart-instance-processes). It's working and it starts all instances but after it successfully starts them it just hangs. If I `Ctrl-C` out and then check the instances with either `service status` or looking in `ps` they're all successfully started, so I don't know what it's doing when it's hanging.

Here's my script:

```
description "all-my-workers"

start on runlevel [2345]

task

console log

env NUM_INSTANCES=1
env STARTING_PORT=42002

pre-start script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_INSTANCES`;
  do
    start my-worker N=$i PORT=$(($STARTING_PORT + $i))
  done
end script
```

When I do `service start all-my-workers` I get this:

```
vagrant@vagrant-service:/etc/init$ sudo service all-my-workers start
```

And then it just hangs there and doesn't prompt me again. As I said I can `Ctrl-C` out and see the running workers:

```
vagrant@vagrant-service:/etc/init$ sudo service all-my-workers status
all-my-workers start/running
vagrant@vagrant-service:/etc/init$ sudo service my-worker status N=1
my-worker (1) start/running, process 21938
```

And in `ps`:

```
worker    21938  0.0  0.1   4392   612 ?        Ss   21:46   0:00 /bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
worker    21941  0.2  7.3 174076 27616 ?        Sl   21:46   0:00 python /var/lib/my-system/script/start_worker.py
```

I don't think the problem is in the `my-worker.conf` but just in case:

```
description "my-worker"

stop on stopping all-my-workers

setuid worker
setgid worker

respawn

instance $N

console log

env SCRIPT_PATH="/var/lib/my-system/script/"

script
    export PROVIDER=vagrant
    export REGION=all
    export ENVIRONMENT=cert

    . /var/lib/my-system/.virtualenvs/my-system/bin/activate

    python $SCRIPT_PATH/start_worker.py

    END
end script
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## How Do I Fix It?

I'm going to assume that `my-worker` is a long-lived process, and you want to have any easy way to spin up & tear down multiple parallel instances of `my-worker`.

If this is the case, you probably *don't* want `all-my-workers` to be a `task`. You'd want the following instead:

```
description "all-my-workers"

start on runlevel [2345]

console log

env NUM_INSTANCES=1
env STARTING_PORT=42002

pre-start script
    for i in `seq 1 $NUM_INSTANCES`;
    do
        start my-worker N=$i PORT=$(($STARTING_PORT + $i))
    done
end script

pre-stop script
    for i in `seq 1 $NUM_INSTANCES`;
    do
        stop my-worker N=$i PORT=$(($STARTING_PORT + $i)) || true
    done
end script
```

Then you can run `start all-my-workers` to start all of the `my-worker` instances and then run `stop all-my-workers` to stop them. Effectively, `all-my-workers` becomes a parent job that manages starting and stoping it's child jobs.

## Why?

You cited two SO answers showing this idea of a parent job managing child jobs. They show:

1. A *task* with a `script` stanza
2. A *job* with a `pre-start` stanza

Your parent job is a *task* with a `pre-start` stanza, and that's why you're running into this odd behavior.

#### script vs pre-start

From [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/346319) which cites [this deprecated documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), there are two very important statements (with emphasis added):

> All job files must have either an exec or script stanza. **This specifies what will be run for the job.**
>
> Additional shell code can be given to be run *before* or *after* the binary or script specified with exec or script. **These are not expected to start the process, in fact, they can't. They are intended for preparing the environment and cleaning up afterwards.**

In summary, any background processes spawned by the `pre-start` stanza are ignored (i.e., not monitored) by Upstart. Instead, you *must* use `exec` or `script` to spawn a process which Upstart will monitor.

What happens if you omit the `exec`/`script` stanza? Upstart will sit and wait for a process to be spawned. Thus, you might as well have written a while-true loop:

```
script
    while true; do
        true
    done
end script
```

The only difference is that the while-true loop is a live-lock whereas an empty stanza results in a dead-lock.

#### Jobs vs. Tasks

Knowing the above, [the Upstart documentation for tasks](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#task) finally leads us to what's going on:

> Without the 'task' keyword, **the events that cause the job to start will be unblocked as soon as the job is started**. This means the job has emitted a starting(7) event, run its pre-start, begun its script/exec, and post-start, and emitted its started(7) event.
>
> With task, **the events that lead to this job starting will be blocked until the job has completely transitioned back to stopped**. This means that the job has run up to the previously mentioned started(7) event, and has also completed its post-stop, and emitted its stopped(7) event.

(Some of the specifics about events and states will make more sense if you read the documenation about [starting and stopping jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#starting-a-job)).

In simpiler terms:

- With a normal Upstart job, the `exec`/`script` stanza is expected to block indefinitely because it's launching a long-lived process. Thus, Upstart stops blocking once it has finished the `pre-start` stanza.
- With a `task`, the `exec`/`script` stanza is expected to block for a "finite" period because it's launching a short-lived process. Thus, Ubstart blocks until **after** the `exec`/`script` stanza has completed.

But what happens if there is no `exec`/`script` stanza? Upstart sits and waits indefinitely for something to be launched, but that's *never going to happen*.

- In the case of a `job`, that's fine because Upstart doesn't block while waiting for a process to spawn, and calling `stop` is apparently enough to make it stop waiting.
- In the case of a `task`, though, Upstart will just sit and hang forever -- or until you interrupt it. However, because it still hasn't found a spawned process, it is still technically running. That's is why you're able to query the status after interrupting and see `all-my-workers start/running`.

## For Interest's Sake

If, for some reason, you really wanted to make your parent job into a task, you would actually need **two** tasks: one to start the `my-worker` instances and one to stop them. You would also need to delete the `stop on stopping all-my-workers` stanza from `my-worker`.

**start-all-my-workers:**

```
description "starts all-my-workers"

start on runlevel [2345]

task

console log

env NUM_INSTANCES=1
env STARTING_PORT=42002

script
    for i in `seq 1 $NUM_INSTANCES`;
    do
        start my-worker N=$i PORT=$(($STARTING_PORT + $i))
    done
end script
```

**stop-all-my-workers:**

```
description "stops all-my-workers"

start on runlevel [!2345]

task

console log

env NUM_INSTANCES=1
env STARTING_PORT=42002

script
    for i in `seq 1 $NUM_INSTANCES`;
    do
        stop my-worker N=$i PORT=$(($STARTING_PORT + $i)) || true
    done
end script
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is by far the best answer I've ever received on SO :) Very informative!!